# Symfony Secrets are slowing down every page loading

Tags: php, symfony

I want to store sensitive API keys inside my Symfony code, so I tried using secrets : [Symfony secrets](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/secrets.html)

I installed secrets via composer, and added my two keys : CLIENT_ID, and CLIENT_SECRET, following the instructions of the documentation.
I then added the env variables inside the `services.yaml` file, inside the parameters:

```yaml
parameters:
    clientId: "%env(CLIENT_ID)%"
    clientSecret: "%env(CLIENT_SECRET)%"
```

I then added the variables from the constructor, via the AbstractController to a Service, and tried to get the keys :

```php
    public function __construct($clientId, $clientSecret)
    {
        $this->clientId=$clientId;
        $this->clientSecret=$clientSecret;
    }

    private function performGetRequest()
    {
        $clientId=$this->clientId;
        $clientSecret=$this->clientSecret;
    }
```

I can get the keys, and the API request works, but every page loading takes ages to load (~10s), Symfony Profiler informs me that the `controller`, is taking all the loading time.

Even when I am removing the request for the variables inside the `services.yaml` file, it is this long. It loads for ages as soon as the variables are stored inside the secrets files. I tried this both in DEV and PROD envs, and it performs the same.

Do you have an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure it's the *injection of secrets*, and not the *usage of those secrets* that's slowing the page down? E.g. what happens if you inject them, but then simply send a plain text `Ok` response?

Comment: Can we assume that other controllers are working just fine?  Does bin/console secrets:list --reveal work as expected? Are you doing docker stuff?

Comment: I am sure the injection of secrets are an issue in the DEV environment, and I don't really know why. Someone suggested that it was because of windows not being efficient for this, but I didn't manage to make it work efficiently on the DEV env. 
And the controllers are indeed working just fine, as well as the secrets reveal. 

It actually works in PROD env, so I'll stick to it, but if you have any clue about it I'd be happy to try your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Symfony secrets, Symfony will check if the CLIENT_ID and CLIENT-SECRET env variables exists. If yes, it will use it (but this is not your case). If not, Symfony will decrypt it from the crypted values: it is the decryption process wich took ages.

So to improve performances, you need to decrypt first your secrets (https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/secrets.html#deploy-secrets-to-production). You can do it thanks to the command `SECRETS=prod php bin/console secrets:decrypt-to-local --force` But be careful this will decrypt it in a `.env.prod.local` file, wich may not be safe. You might prefer to decrypt your secrets during deployement and define env var only in your CI stack. Don't forget to delete temporary decrypted files.

Comment: It shouldn't take 10s to decrypt two secrets, though.